# Error to obtain coordinate reference system argument from a raster image in R

Tags: raster, coordinate-system, r, error

I got an error when i wanted to obtain the CRS from stacklayer. I don´t know what could it be. I need some advice or help to obtain it.
 This is my code.

```
#LOAD RASTER LIBRARY
>library(rgdal)
>library(raster)
>ndvi<-raster('ndvi2005.tif')
>ndvi2<-raster('ndvi2006.tif')

#RASTER STACK
>stk <- stack(ndvi1, ndvi2)
#DISPLAY STK
>stk
class       : RasterStack 
dimensions  : 1160, 1573, 1824680, 2  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution  : 0.008627311, 0.008627319  (x, y)
extent      : -74.49244, -60.92168, -20.00769, -10  (xmin, xmax, ymin,    ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
names       : ndvi2005, ndvi2006 
min values  :       NA,       NA 
max values  :       NA,       NA
```

then I changed the NA values

```
>stk[stk==0]<- NA
>stk
class       : RasterBrick 
dimensions  : 1160, 1573, 1824680, 2  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution  : 0.008627311, 0.008627319  (x, y)
extent      : -74.49244, -60.92168, -20.00769, -10  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
data source : in memory
names       : ndvi2005, ndvi2006 
min values  :     -0.3,     -0.3 
max values  :   0.9990,   0.9993
```

then when i wanted to obtain de coordinate reference system with `CRS()` i got the next message

```
>cord<-CRS(stk)
>Error in !is.na(projargs) && !nzchar(projargs) : 
 invalid 'x' type in 'x && y'
```

I know that my projection is `+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0` but i have in total 100 stacklayers in differents proyections that i need to analize each one, but i dont know what is my mistake or is something wrong with my code because then i want to use the output of `CRS(stk)`in the function `raster(...., CRS=cord)` as an input.

Comment: Use projection()  not CRS. Sp  weirdly has two functions for this, really painful

Comment: You could also proj4string which is the sp convention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

due to the comments i did this.

```
>cord<-projection(stk, asText = F)
>cord
CRS arguments:
 +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0
```

But now whe i used `cord`as an input in the function `raster(nrows,ncols,CRS=cord)` i got an error because `cord` had to be text, so i did this.

```
>cord<-projection(stk, asText = T)
```

and finally works.

Comment: You only need CRS to wrap the string for some sp functions, but notably not for spTransform any more. Suggest always use string with raster::projection for set and get. raster adds a lot of usability to sp, but it's ad hoc unfortunately and not always adopted by sp

Comment: Yes that is true. thanks for the suggestion @mdsumner

Answer (score 1):

CRS is an interface class and is not supposed to work like that. Use `projection(raster)`  or `proj4string(raster)`.

Answer (score -1):

use `crs` instead of `CRS`.
Read rgdal package for see the differences.

Comment: maybe you could add a reference to exactly >where< in the rgdal package one should look. Or you could add a quote of the relevant part